# Migrating 3D Project from QT 5.4.0 to QT 6 with QT3D: File Format Recommendations

Tags: 3dsmax, collada, qt3d

I am working on a project where we have QML and 3D components, and we are currently using QT version 5.4.0. I am in the process of porting it to QT 6 and considering the use of QT3D.

With our current setup in version 5.4.0, we create 3D files in 3DSMax and export them in the .dae (Collada format). However, we have encountered some issues with Collada files during the export process.

Therefore, I would like to seek your suggestions regarding which file format I should use for exporting the 3D files - either .3ds, .fbx, or .dae (as we have been using). I also attempted to export in .3ds format and use Assimp with QT, but I came across information on the internet suggesting that .3ds format sometimes does not include scenes and animations.

Could you please provide guidance on this matter?

Thanks.

Suggestions which format will be better for 3d file